# How can I see images from my ftp server on Ubuntu, directly from browser in the form of a gallery?

Tags: server, software-recommendation, ftp, aws, online-storage

I have Ubuntu installed on AWS running an FTP server.

Images are uploaded continuously to the FTP server.

Is it possible to view the images directly in the form of a gallery?

Could I use Ubuntu's gallery app, or access them on-line, perhaps using a web browser?

The images are already sorted.

For example - when I entered into ftp server with id and password I want a gallery instead of a boring ftp file look

Comment: How are your images sorted and what size are the image files?

Comment: Do you want to access your image gallery from more than one device?

Comment: I want to view as an online image gallery from my browser. n i have script running in my ftp server from crontab thats sorts images according to the date. I just need a online image gallery based GUI that can show my sorted folder. and this images are cam images small size.

Comment: Will it be public or private?

Comment: its private the user has ftp login id and passwd

Answer (score 0):

You could try to install a web application on the server.

Try: [node-gallery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gallery).

Comment: I want to view the images we view it in a dropbox like Google Drive(with thumbnails).